# Compare with an existing input value and then set a new value in the existing input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this form where I am getting the full state Value (`input` `type="hidden"` `id="state_code"` `name="state_code"` `value="Pennsylvania"`) , but when I need to submit the form, I need to update the full state value with state code.

For example if the state value is "Pennsylvania", then I need to update that with "PA".

The state value is dynamic so it could be any state and I need to update it accordingly. How can I do that?

Here is my form:

```
<form
  class="needs-validation"
  action=""
  id="lead-form"
  method="POST"
  novalidate=""
>
  <div class="input-group">
    <input
      type="email"
      id="email"
      class="form-control"
      size="20"
      maxlength="80"
      placeholder="Enter your email"
      required=""
    />
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="Status" value="New" />
  <input type="hidden" name="Brand__c" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="lead_source" value="Web Lead Gen Form" />
  <input type="hidden" name="Market_ID__c" value="CPG" />
  <input type="hidden" name="MS_ID__c" value="6" />

  <input type="hidden" id="state_code" name="state_code" value="Pennsylvania" />
  <input type="hidden" name="zip" value="15001" />
  <input type="hidden" name="country_code" value="US" />

  <input type="submit" name="Submit" class="button-orange" />
</form>
```

Comment: Hi, this question is too broad. We need to see what you have tried first.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you need to addEventListener to input that you want listen to.
HTML:

```
<input type="text" name="Thing" value="" />
```

Script:

```
/* event listener */
document.getElementsByName("Thing")[0].addEventListener('change', doThing);

/* function */
function doThing(){
   alert('Horray! Someone wrote "' + this.value + '"!');
}
```

You need also to initialize some variable, which you will update based on your input. Also if you need to shorten states,  you need to make some kind of vocabulary function that will convert to your desired output.